# How to insert values into a stored string constant value

Tags: java

How to insert values into a store string value.

I have a stored constant before my method that I will be using for a count variable

Then in my `getCount` method I have passed in `Smith`, but it is not getting into the constant when it is called.

```
public static final String TEST = String.format("SELECT count(first_name) FROM students WHERE last_name = %s",lastName);

    public getCount(String lastName){

        String lastName2 ="";
        lastName2 = lastName;

        count = TEST;
```

But when I print this out to the screen it says the TEST constant is `SELECT count(first_name) FROM students WHERE last_name = lastName"`  instead of `Smith`

how can I get this value in here?

Comment: You should really learn how to accept more answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constant is only initialized once, (a variable defined as `final` cannot be changed once it is set) when you first run the program.

Make it a method instead:

```
String getSelectString(String lastName) {
    return String.format("SELECT count(first_name) FROM students WHERE last_name = %s", lastName);
}
```

Then you call the method whenever you want to access your "constant". (Which isn't really a constant)

```
public getCount(String lastName) {
    (...)
    count = getSelectString(lastName);
    (...)
}
```